# What is a good tool to scrub MetaData from files?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, cleaning, metadata

I am curious if there is a good program that will remove MetaData from multiple document types?  Some programs have a "prepare document" feature but it generally only applies to one file type or extension.  I am looking for something that can process a dissimilar group of files types at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved same issue with Office 2003/XP Add-in: Remove Hidden Data

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=144e54ed-d43e-42ca-bc7b-5446d34e5360&displaylang=en#Requirements

Comment: That link is a 404, but that's probably because it's [a built-in function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-presentations-or-workbooks-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f) now (as of late 2023).

Answer (score 2):

BatchPurifier - http://www.digitalconfidence.com/BatchPurifier.html can remove metadata from 18 file types (MS Office, OpenOffice, PDF, etc)

Comment: Can confirm that this still works in 2023 on at least a simple test Excel file, and functions in Wine on Linux with no problems. It is commercial software, not free. It is also seat-licensed, locked to whatever computer you first install it on.